# how to delete a specific queue in activemq

Tags: java, activemq-classic, messaging, jmx

i want to delete a specific queue from consumer after getting the message from queue in activemq. i read many articles but none of them giving good explanation.i can provide either queue name or correlationID for deleting the queue. please give some suggestion.

version :-Activemq 5.8.0 . advance thanks

Comment: how do you want to delete the queue, from java code, or some admin console? There is API on JMS to delete a queue, and ActiveMQ has JMX API to delete queues also

Comment: @ClausIbsen Thanks for the reply. i got the answer. i want to delete from java code.i did using this link http://www.consulting-notes.com/2010/08/monitoring-and-managing-activemq-with.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer.delete a queue programmatically from a java program

```
 JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi");
JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url);
MBeanServerConnection conn = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();

String operationName="removeQueue"; //operation like addQueue or removeQueue
String parameter="Payment_Check";   // Queue name
ObjectName activeMQ = new ObjectName("org.apache.activemq:brokerName=localhost,type=Broker");
if(parameter != null) {
    Object[] params = {parameter};
    String[] sig = {"java.lang.String"};
    conn.invoke(activeMQ, operationName, params, sig);
} else {
    conn.invoke(activeMQ, operationName,null,null);
}
```

you want to change in activemq config file.in default createConnector="false".change to createConnector="true".otherwise you will get error like

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException.
```

this concept is explained in "ben.odey"'s article "managing ActiveMQ with JMX APIs".
Link:- [managing ActiveMQ with JMX APIs](http://www.consulting-notes.com/2010/08/monitoring-and-managing-activemq-with.html)

Comment: Needed to use this as the ObjectName: `org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=localhost,Type=Broker`

Answer (score 0):

I also get like your problem. I fixed like that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24905235/delete-specific-queue-when-clients-idle-time-in-activemq). It is using `QueueViewMBean`. Which have `removeMessage` function. You just need to pass `messageid`.